# Should I use multicolumn index or two 1-column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table which I currently define as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE pairs (  
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
p1 INTEGER,
p2 INTEGER,
r  INTEGER,
UNIQUE(p1, p2) ON CONFLICT IGNORE,
FOREIGN KEY (p1) REFERENCES points(id),
FOREIGN KEY (p2) REFERENCES points(id)
)
```

After that it is filled with gigabytes of data. Now I will need to do a lot of selects exactly like this:

```
SELECT id, r FROM pairs WHERE p1 = 666 OR p2 = 666
```

So the question is: what indexes I should create to speed up this select?

```
CREATE INDEX p1_index ON pairs(p1)
CREATE INDEX p2_index ON pairs(p2)
```

or may be

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX p_index ON pairs(p1, p2)
```

or may be even both? (and buy a new HDD for them).
SQLite3 does not create automatically index for a `UNIQUE` constraint on multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the OR condition, I would go with multiple indexes. If it was an AND condition then a multi-column index would work better.

For the OR condition:
The optimizer will start looking at one of the indexes, finds a match and just grabs that row. The other index will only be looked at when there is no match with the first one. **On multi-processor systems, both the indexes will be (should be) scanned in parallel too.** Awesome, right?

For the AND condition:
If 2 indexes are available, the optimizer will have to look at both of them, merge the output of the two index scans and then fetch the results from the base table. This may turn out to be expensive. Here, a multi-column index would have been great.

But then again, the optimizer may choose a different path based on the available table and index statistics.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to check if indexes are used.

For your example query, both the single-column indexes would be used:

```
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT id, r FROM pairs WHERE p1 = 666 OR p2 = 666;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pairs USING INDEX p1_index (p1=?) (~10 rows)
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pairs USING INDEX p2_index (p2=?) (~10 rows)
```

The multi-column index (which you already have because of the UNIQUE constraint) would be used if the lookup of a single record needs both columns:

```
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT id, r FROM pairs WHERE p1 = 666 AND p2 = 666;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pairs USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_pairs_1 (p1=? AND p2=?) (~1 rows)
```

However, a multi-column index can also be used for lookups on its first column(s):

```
> DROP INDEX p1_index;
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT id, r FROM pairs WHERE p1 = 666 OR p2 = 666;
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pairs USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_pairs_1 (p1=?) (~10 rows)
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE pairs USING INDEX p2_index (p2=?) (~10 rows)
```

Also see the documentation:
[Query Optimizer Overview](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html),
[Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).

Comment: When I use .indices to see what indexes I have, it shows auto-index for primary key column, but no index for UNIQUE constraint. I think it creates index only if UNIQUE is defined in column description, not as a separate statement.

Comment: `.indices` does not show internal indexes (like `sqlite_autoindex_pairs_1` in my example).